# Android icon gets picked up instead of notification icon

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM notification and I have set the following in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/splash" />
<!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming notification message.  -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/splash_color" />
```

where **splash** is a transparent png image.

I also have the android app icon which I am setting like this in the same manifest file:

```
 <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="myapp"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```

What happens is that when a notification pops up, it picks up the **ic_launcher** instead of splash. If I replace **ic_launcher** and keep splash as my android icon, then I see the notification icon.

However, if I do it this way, then my app icon (which is now a transparent image) get's a black color as background which I don't want. I want the **ic_launcher** to be my  background color.  I fail to understand as to why the image defined at **android:icon** gets picked up for notification ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this, please put the meta-tags right after the application tag. Do not put them under the activity tag. So something like this:

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="When Coin"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```